# PIN Block Calculation in Swift

Tags: ios, encryption

how to implement this steps in swift

> - Get the encrypted **TWK** in this format **e077b34665f66eb5**.
> - Get clear TWK by decrypt TWK using the stored **TMK** when TMK is **abcdef0123456789** using DES as decryption method.
> - Prepare PIN block using ANSI X9.8 (ISO Format 0) format as follows:
>
>   1. Calculate P1: [0][pin_length][pin] then right padded with 'F's, example for PIN = "0000", P1:"040000FFFFFFFFFF"
>   2. Calculate P2: Get account from PAN by taking the last 12 digits of the PAN not including the Luhn code and left padded with zeros, example for PAN = "1234567890123456", P2:"0000456789012345"
>   3. clear PIN Block = p1 XOR p2, for above P1 and P2 = 0400459876fedcba
> - Encrypt the PIN block using the clear TWK key and DES as encryption method.

ii try to do it with CommonCrypto

```
class Handeller{

var pinBlock:String  = "";

func Handeller(tmk:String , workingKey:String ,pan:String ,pin:String){

    var p1:String = ""
    var p2:String = ""

    p1.append("0")
    p1.append(String(pin.count))
    p1.append(pin)

    var i:Int = 0
    for i in 0...15-p1.count{
        p1.append("F")
    }

    p2.append("0000")
    var y:Int = 0
    for i in 0...11{
        let panChar = pan.characters.map { (Character) -> Character in
            return Character
        }
        p2.append(panChar[pan.count-13+i])

    }


    print(p1)
    print(p2)

    // to get clear workingKey
    print(myDecrypt(mykey: tmk, myString: workingKey))

    let text = [UInt8](p1.utf8)
    let cipher = [UInt8](p2.utf8)

    var encrypted = [UInt8]()
    print("text \(text)")
    // encrypt bytes
    //for t in enumerate(text) {
    for (index, t) in text.enumerated(){
        encrypted.append(t ^ cipher[index])
    }
    var str = String(bytes: encrypted, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    print(str)
    for (index, t) in encrypted.enumerated(){
        print(t)
    }
    print("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")
    for (index, t) in encrypted.enumerated(){
        print(String(t, radix: 16))
    }
    String(bytes: encrypted, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(toByteArray(String(bytes: encrypted, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!))



}
func myDecrypt (mykey:String , myString:String) -> String{
    //let tmkByte = String(mykey).utf8.map{ UInt8($0) }


    print("key is \(mykey)")
    print("data is \(myString)")
    if
        let key = mykey.data(using: .utf8),
        let data = myString.data(using: .utf8)
        //let data = Data(Hex: myString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) //<-#1
    {
        print("key  byte num is \(key)")
        print("data byte num is \(data)")

        var numBytesDecrypted: size_t = 0
        var result = Data(count: data.count)    //<-#2
        print("result length \(result)")

        let err = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {resultBytes in
            data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
                key.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                    CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt), CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmDES), CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding|kCCModeECB), keyBytes, kCCKeySizeDES, nil, dataBytes, data.count, resultBytes, result.count, &numBytesDecrypted) //<-#4
                }
            }
        }

        if err != CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) {
            NSLog("Decryption failed! Error: \(err.description)")
        }


        print(numBytesDecrypted)
        result.count = numBytesDecrypted //<-#3
        print(result as NSData) //`as NSData` is good for debugging.
       //let NSDATA = result as NSData
       //init?(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)
       //print ("string is \(result.hexEncodedString())")

        return String(data: result , encoding: .utf8) ?? "???1"
        //return result.hexEncodedString()
    }
    return "???2"
}
func toByteArray( _ hex:String ) -> [UInt8] {

    // remove "-" from Hexadecimal
    var hexString = hex.removeWord( "-" )

    let size = hexString.characters.count / 2
    var result:[UInt8] = [UInt8]( repeating: 0, count: size ) // array with length = size

    // for ( int i = 0; i < hexString.length; i += 2 )
    for i in stride( from: 0, to: hexString.characters.count, by: 2 ) {

        let subHexStr = hexString.subString( i, length: 2 )

        result[ i / 2 ] = UInt8( subHexStr, radix: 16 )! // ! - because could be null
    }

    return result
}}

extension Data {
func hexEncodedString() -> String {
    return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
}}
extension String {

func subString( _ from: Int, length: Int ) -> String {

    let size = self.characters.count

    let to = length + from
    if from < 0 || to > size {

        return ""
    }

    var result = ""

    for ( idx, char ) in self.characters.enumerated() {

        if idx >= from && idx < to {

            result.append( char )
        }
    }

    return result
}

func removeWord( _ word:String ) -> String {

    var result = ""

    let textCharArr = Array( self.characters )
    let wordCharArr = Array( word.characters )

    var possibleMatch = ""

    var i = 0, j = 0
    while i < textCharArr.count {

        if textCharArr[ i ] == wordCharArr[ j ] {

            if j == wordCharArr.count - 1 {

                possibleMatch = ""
                j = 0
            }
            else {

                possibleMatch.append( textCharArr[ i ] )
                j += 1
            }
        }
        else {

            result.append( possibleMatch )
            possibleMatch = ""

            if j == 0 {

                result.append( textCharArr[ i ] )
            }
            else {

                j = 0
                i -= 1
            }
        }

        i += 1
    }

    return result
}}
```

i call it in parms

```
let h = Handeller()
h.Handeller(tmk: "abcdef0123456789", workingKey: "e077b34665f66eb5", pan: "1234432109874567", pin: "0000")
```

Comment: Please show your efforts, e.g. code you've created

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) articles and note that Stackoverflow is not a freelance platform - if you search someone who can do the job, search somewhere else.

Comment: thanks  for your interactiv  , i hope i found answer